# OAuth authentication authorization

Tags: security, oauth, jwt

i am totally confused about the usage of OAuth and i am not sure how to use oauth for my szenario. At the moment i use a "pure" JWT approach which looks like that:

1. Client (JavaScript Application) send login and password to my Rest-Endpoint (Server (Java)).
2. Server validate user informationen, read / generate some user roles and wrap it in a JWT Token (with a secret)
3. Server send JWT Token back to client
4. Client will perform additional Rest-Calls with Authorizationen Header
5. Server validates Token with private secret and grand access based on roles/user

Now i think about the usage of OAuth but i am confused how to use it to realize the szenario.

1. I registered an application at "auth0".
2. I use a JS library to redirect to the login process of auth0, login via auth0 account and consume the id_token and access_token

=  i can send the id_token (JWT with RSA256) to my rest api, validate it with the public certificate and can extract some user information

but:

a) i have read that i should not use the id_token to access my api. Instead i should use the access_token (which is not in JWT format and will not give me any information about the user) and use the access_token to query for the user information? That whould be the case for every request?!

b) i don't see the point where the user roles come into play. When i have some operations (rest endpoints) which are only allowed for "admins" or "customers". I don't see any possibility to define them.

You see i am a little bit confused, i hope somebody can clarify all the things.
Thanks a lot
Chris

Answer (score 0):

a) Both tokens you use should be in JWT format and you should use access_token for authenticated queries. The access_token not necessarily contains information about the user, so on server side you usually can decide only that the token is emitted by the token service and is valid. If all these checks are passed, you should accept it as an authenticated user.

b) User roles can be placed into the access_token's payload section as an additive claim (e.g. role=admin,datawriter or role=customer,listreader) like many other things.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

a) Sounds like you are getting an **opaque** access_token back and not a JWT.  You'll need to create an **API** in Auth0 (similar to the application/client you already created).  Then you pass that identifier in the `audience` parameter when you authenticate.  Then you should get a JWT back, and that will have a `sub` parameter which is the Auth0 ID of the user, which can help you identify who the user is.  I believe you could also use Auth0 rules if you need to put more identification info into the token.  See here for a full explanation of the opaque vs. JWT access token: https://auth0.com/docs/tokens/access-token

b) Roles are tricky.  I believe Auth0 would suggest that you create scopes on your API, and then request the scopes needed during login.  Auth0 Rules would then be used as a sort of "glue", to adjust scopes that were requested but not permitted for the authenticated user.  They also have an Authorization Extension you can use to help facilitate some of this.  Another option could be storing role info in the user metadata, and using rules to put that info into the token.  Finally, the option we chose was to not use Auth0 to define our roles.  We let Auth0 authenticate, and once authenticated we check access in our system for the authorization side of things.  Lots of options.